# What are the password insertion attempts for a Seagate ST9500325AS?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, passwords

I have forgot the master password for my ST9500325AS hard drive in my Lenovo G560 laptop. The password attempts to insert the password is 2 times per power up. That means that I can make 2 wrong attempts and I have to power off the computer, then on again, to try again 2 times and so on. I have tried several power ups and I'm worried if at some point I reach a certain number of attempts that would lock the whole thing for good.

I've noticed that master passwords are pretty hard to go around, so my best bet is to use my rusty memory; given the fact that it has been a long time since I've created the password (since I bought the computer or something). I of course remember the user password because I use it all the time; so I have access to the drive.

How many wrong attempts would the drive take before locking for good, if any?